# How to convert foreign string representations of number with decimals into doubles?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I am at an internship where there is parsing done on strings read from a XML file. Specifically the strings are representations of decimal numbers. A problem arises when I try to parse a decimal string formatted differently than the ones that have comma separators and a decimal point. For example the way that nations format their decimal numbers differently:

- France: 1 234 567,89 == 1,234,567.89
- Germany: 1.234.567,89 == 1,234,567.89
- Australia: 1 234 567.89 == 1,234,567,89

I'm pretty sure that's how those countries can represent decimal numbers. If not sorry. Point is 1,234,567.89 may be represented many ways.

What I would like to do is ensure that whatever string representation of a decimal number I try to parse it ought to come out 1,234,567.89.

I thought that a good way to go about this would be to use the `double.TryParse()` method but I have been unable to get it to work.

Here is what I got in just a little test application:

```
double num;
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("1 234 567,89", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out num).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("1.234.567,89", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out num).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("1 234 567.89", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out num).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
```

Where all I do is check to see that `TryParse` worked and then print the number. In this case TryParse always outputs false. The false means that `TryParse` caught a `FormatException` and it obviously failed converting the string to a double.

Does this look right or am I just completely confused about what I am doing?

I'm under the impression that by saying `NumberStyles.Any` it indicates that the string can be in any form of a decimal number. I am also under the impression that saying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat` returns the formatting information of numbers that are culturally independent. In other words it will create a decimal of the form 1,234,567.89.

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Different culture have different thousands separators, decimal separators and more, so you need to use the appropriate `CultureInfo` for the culture.

You are using `InvariantCulture` for all of them - it stands for no culture at all and by default, the specific number separators are the same as the ones for `en-US`.

For example, if you want to parse a number that is in a French format, example taken  from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) (slightly modified):

```
double number;
string value = "1345,978";
NumberStyle style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
if (Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
```

> Displays:
>
> Converted '1345,978' to 1345.978.

Comment: I guess I used CultureInfo.InvariantCulture wrong as I thought it was what it was going to be converted too. Not what the culture the string was from. Is there a "All Cultures"? I didn't see anything in MSDN that jumped out to me.

Comment: @Chris - no, no such thing. One of the things that define a culture is specific numeric formatting (which includes thousands separators, decimal separators etc).

Answer (score 1):

This does the job in any scenario. Its a little bit parsing.

```
List<string> inputs = new List<string>()
{
    "1.234.567,89",
    "1 234 567,89",
    "1 234 567.89",
    "1,234,567.89",
    "123456789",
    "1234567,89",
    "1234567.89",
};
string output;

foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    // unify string (no spaces, only . )
    output = input.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");

    // split it on points
    string[] split = output.Split('.');

    if (split.Count() > 1)
    {
        // take all parts except last
        output = string.Join("", split.Take(split.Count()-1).ToArray());

        // combine token parts with last part
        output = string.Format("{0}.{1}", output, split.Last());
    }

    // parse double invariant
    double d = double.Parse(output, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're always guaranteed to have the cents 1,234,567.00, you can ignore all the punctuation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you all agree on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat`. You may try some formal specification like XSD that can be validated automatically.